# ASP.NET CSV Excel issue with strange characters

Tags: c#, vb.net, csv, export-to-excel

I'm exporting a table of data to CSV format, e.g.:

```
    "COL1","COL2","COL3"
    "1","some text", "£232.00"
    "2","some more text", "£111.00"
    "3","other text", "£2.00"
```

The code to export is fairly simple using an ashx handler:

```
    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=data.csv")
    context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate")
    context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "must-revalidate")
    context.Response.Write(data)
    context.Response.Flush()
    context.Response.End()
```

My issue is when Excel tries to open the exported file the character `Â` appears before all `£` signs, e.g. `Â£232.00` when the value should be `£232.00`.

Comment: This looks like a Unicode to UTF-8 translation error. I don't know offhand how to fix it, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the encoding i.e. the `Response.ContentEncoding` property.

After finally looking this up in Reflector, the default `ContentEncoding` is likely to be `Encoding.Default` or `Encoding.UTF8`, if a `system.web/globalization` config section exists, unless it is overridden by a `responseEncoding` property in that config section.

As to whether setting the `ContentEncoding` property at all performs differently to not doing so:

- If you set it to the same object as its current setting, it explicitly catches that and does nothing;
- However, if you change the setting, it calls `HttpWriter.UpdateResponseEncoding`, which calls `HttpWriter.FlushCharBuffer` before switching to the new encoding if there's anything buffered to write already.
- If you do not set `ContentEncoding` it is set to the default I mentioned above by first reference to `HttpWriter.UpdateResponseEncoding`, which is definitely called before any content is written because `HttpWriter._responseEncodingUpdated` is checked in the writing methods and only updated to `True` at the end of `HttpWriter.UpdateResponseEncoding`.

As such, I believe the OP needed to change the encoding to `Unicode` and I assume Phil Hale's comment means he had a `system.web/globalization` config section that needed overriding.

Notes:

- The existing code calling `Response.Clear` only affects content, not headers, so, contrary to my previous suggestion, I *don't* believe it is relevant, other than removing any chance of existing content to be present to be flushed before the `ContentEncoding` change.
- This is based upon the Reflector 6 output from `System.Web` from .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: thanks for the tips this solved it

            "context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode"

Comment: I fixed this by adding `Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;`. Not really sure why this works to be honest

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - others didn't

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
```